# How to link data from two spreadsheets imported to sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I imported 2 spreadsheets to SQL Server tables. One sheet has data containing persons name & surname, the project they are working on as well as there banking details. The other spreadsheet has only the names & surnames  of persons and banking details.

Sheet 2 data needs to be grouped to the right projects like in sheet 1. The only connection I found is that the `Reference` column in Sheet 2 has numbers that match the `ParentID` on sheet 1 but with a suffix appended.

Beneficiaries with the same `ParentID` belong to the same Project. I need a way to extract the numeric values of `Reference` and match them to the corresponding `ParentID` in order to group the Beneficiaries in the right project.

sheet 1 :

```
BeneficiaryID      float         Checked
BeneficiaryName    nvarchar(255) Checked
BeneficiarySurname nvarchar(255) Checked
IDNumber           float         Checked
DOB                nvarchar(255) Checked
BranchnameID       nvarchar(255) Checked
BranchCode         float         Checked
AccountType        nvarchar(255) Checked
AccountNumber      float         Checked
TotalWages         float         Checked
[(No column name)] float         Checked
ParentId           float         Checked
PPRDate            datetime      Checked
```

sheet 2 :

```
Reference     nvarchar(255) Checked
[Account No]  nvarchar(255) Checked
[Branch No]   nvarchar(255) Checked
[Bank Name]   nvarchar(255) Checked
[Acc Type]    nvarchar(255) Checked
Amount        nvarchar(255) Checked
[Action Date] nvarchar(255) Checked
Status        nvarchar(255) Checked
```

Here is some sample 
sheet 1

```
BeneficiaryID   BeneficiaryName     BeneficiarySurname   IDNumber   DOB Branchname ID   BranchCode  AccountNumber   TotalWages      ParentId    PPRDate    Caption

1202            Chris               Manda                123456     4/6/1995 1               ABC         123             120          10125    June 2018  Agriculture
```

sheet 2

```
Reference       Account_No Branch_No    Bank_Name   Amount  Action_Date Status


10125_Motsomane 1234       151258865    CDF         1200    15/01/2016 ERROR
```

Comment: I updated your question by adding these definitions. What field in `sheet2` is also in `sheet1`? I see no field that has the same name/type in both sheets.

Comment: when i type   select * from [sheet1]
  where ParentId = 132857 it groups the beneficiaries with the same ParentID to one project. on sheet 2 the ParentID's are the same as the Reference but Reference has a different data type. i need a way for it to compare all the ParentID against Reference in order to group the beneficiaries to the right project

Comment: Try this statement: `ALTER TABLE Sheet2 ALTER COLUMN Reference FLOAT`, if it doesn't fail then you can match them, if it does then provide some samples with their values since you will have to tamper them a little to be able o match against the floats from the other sheet.

Comment: Reference not only has a different data type, but for the sample data you posted it also has a suffix. It looks like you want to link 10125 to 10125_motsomane. You really need to improve this question a lot if you want a chance at receiving a decent answer. We're here to help but you need to try to make it possible for us to help you.

Comment: You can join on `LEFT(REFERENCE,5)` if you have a fixed-length field

Comment: You can also  use a LIKE: `SELECT * FROM tbl_a a, tbl_b b WHERE CONCAT(a.short_id,'%') LIKE b.long_id`

Answer (score 0):

> The only connection I found is that the Reference column in Sheet 2
>   has numbers that match the ParentID on sheet 1 but with a suffix
>   appended.

You need to match `float` value `10125` (column `ParentID`) on `Sheet1` with `NVarchar(255)` value `10125_Motsomane` (column `Reference`) from `Sheet2`.

If data types would match you would simply do a direct `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    S1.ParentID,
    S2.Reference,
    AnyOtherColumnYouNeed
FROM
    Sheet1 AS S1 
    INNER JOIN Sheet2 AS S2 ON S1.ParentID = S2.Reference
```

But to extract the number before the underscore you can use `CHARINDEX` to find the position of the underscore and then `LEFT` to get the value up to that position:

```
DECLARE @ExampleValue NVARCHAR(255) = N'10125_Motsomane'

SELECT
    Original = @ExampleValue,
    Trimmed = LEFT(
        @ExampleValue,
        CHARINDEX(N'_', @ExampleValue) - 1)
```

Result:

```
Original            Trimmed
10125_Motsomane     10125
```

Applying this on the join (will do an implicit conversion from `NVARCHAR` to `FLOAT`):

```
SELECT
    S1.ParentID,
    S2.Reference,
    AnyOtherColumnYouNeed
FROM
    Sheet1 AS S1 
    INNER JOIN Sheet2 AS S2 ON S1.ParentID = LEFT(S2.Reference, CHARINDEX(N'_', S2.Reference) - 1)
```

Keep in mind that the `LEFT` function will fail if there is no underscore on a value for `Reference`, since it will return `-1` as position.